# React DevTools show components as "Loading..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

I need to debug some props that are being used in my React application. However, if I try to inspect certain components, they appear as "Loading..." instead of the normal props list:
[image]

However, I know that these components have already rendered as I can see them in the DOM. Also, it stays like this perpetually, so it obviously isn't actually loading anything.

I'm using React DevTools `4.2.1-3816ae7c3` and React `16.12.0`

Comment: This is a bug in the new react dev tools. Just reload developer options. You should be able to see the data.

Comment: If by "reload", you mean close and re-open them, it doesn't help for me.

Comment: Is it always loading everytime ? For me its random (say 1/4 times). In that case I switch to a different component or switch to a different DOM element and reload dev tools. Usually it does the fix. If not, try refreshing the browser.

Comment: have the same problem. Have you found anything as solution?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with Ubuntu and after reinstalling the extension. Close the chrome app and reopen it, then it solved it for me.